# iphone, which framework is easy to use for Twitter Dev?

Tags: iphone, twitter

as topic, I am try to use `MGTwitterEngine`, but it seem is trouble to use ....
 also had to got online support, anyone can help so

> Request failed for connectionIdentifier = 45B5868D-F16C-471B-96B2-AE1BEA57C276, error = The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.) ({
>       body = "\n\n  /oauth/access_token\n  Client application is not permitted to use xAuth.\n\n";
>       response = ;

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna need to send Twitter an email requesting that they enable XAuth (which is the authentication system used by MGTwitter) for your application

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth

Comment: @Robin hey sorry for necro'ing this but would you please mark it as an answer if it was what you're looking for ? :)